# iPad : WS-Eventing

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ws-eventing

Can the iPad subscribe to WS-Eventing (Web Service Eventing) notifications?

Because iOS doesn't appear to have native SOAP support, I am guessing not, but need to confirm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you are right: there's no out of the box webservice/soap support,  you have to roll your own.